# how to extract snowflake tables schema and store-procedures using python script?

Tags: python-3.x, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-pipe

I'm intermediate with python and beginner with snowflakes.

Here i'm able to connect snowflakes and fetch table data.

But main problem is to extract tables schema and store-procedures from snowflakes using python script.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the get_ddl feature of snowflake as shown below to get the table schema
[image]

And use `SHOW PROCEDURES` to get the procedures

You can see the below python package to find out how you can run the above queries through python

https://github.com/Infosys/Snowflake-Python-Development-Framework

look at the execute_snowquery function